# Notepad ++ Python script - Calculate in XML Numbers with decimal

Tags: python, xml, notepad++

i have a XML with a.e.

```
    Pos="0.003"
    Pos="100.002"
    Pos="10.2"
    Pos="3.43"
    Pos="0.999"
```

now i want that every tag with get +0.007. i tried it with a python script, but nothing happens. 
What i am doing wrong :(

```py
def calculate(match):
    return 'Pos="\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,4}"' % (match.group(1), complex(match.group(2))+0.007)

    editor.rereplace('Pos="(\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,4})"', calculate)
```

the result should be then

```
    Pos="0.010"
    Pos="100.009"
    Pos="10.207"
    Pos="3.437"
    Pos="1.006"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you are using 2 groups and `complex`, if you want to add `0.007` to each pos, just do:

```
import re
def calculate(match):
    return 'Pos="%s"' % str(float(match.group(1))+0.007)

editor.rereplace('Pos="(\d{1,4}[.]\d{1,4})"', calculate)
```

Comment: thats the solution. thank you! 
now i also dont know why i used 2 groups. Complex is used here because i thought that value do not change due to formating. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your regex only has one group, it should instead be:

```
editor.rereplace('Pos="(\d{1,4})[.](\d{1,4})"', calculate)
```

Also in calculate you don't do the formatting correctly:

```
def calculate(match):
    return 'Pos="%s[.]%s"' % (match.group(1), complex(match.group(2))+0,007)
```

Comment: @Patrick.R Does "doesn't work" mean nothing is changed, or does it mean it is changed to something wrong?

Comment: sorry. it means that the values doesnt change. and i change in the code 0,007 to 0.007. There i made a mistake by copy paste.